# how I can print an array as a vector form

Tags: c++

I want to cout an array as a row vector but when I write:

```
int main() {
    int B[3]={0};
    for (int w = 0; w <2; w++) {
        cout <<"B="<<" "<< B[w] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `B=0 B=0`

But I want output to be like:

`B=(0 0)`

Comment: Print the header out before the loop, print the data in the loop and print the footer after the loop.

Comment: Do you really want only two of the three values printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() {
  int B[3] = { 0 };
  cout << "B=(";
  for (int w = 0; w < 3; w++) {
    cout << B[w];
    if (w < 2) cout << " ";
  }
  cout << ")" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output should be now:
`B=(0 0 0)`

Comment: No, that's not what the output will be.

Comment: fixed space issue

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed size array of only I would probably even prefer a oneliner like this, because I can read it at first glance:

```
cout << "B=(" << B[0] << " " << B[1] << " " << B[2] << ")\n";
```

For a container `B` with a dynamic or very high number of elements `n`, you should probably do something like this:

```
cout << "B=(";
if(n > 0)
{
    cout << B[0];
    // note the iteration should start at 1, because we've already printed B[0]!
    for(int i=1; i < n; i++)
        cout << ", " << B[i]; //I've added a comma here, so you get output like B=(0, 1, 2)
}
cout << ")\n";
```

This has the advantage, that no matter what number of elements, you don't end up with trailing commas or unwanted whitespace.
I'd reccommend making a generic (template) function for the purpose of printing array/std::vector content anyways - it's really useful for debugging purposes!

Comment: Nice answer, the first as far as I can tell. So, welcome to StackOverflow and I hope to see more of you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int B[3]={0};
cout << "B=(";
for (int w = 0; w < 3; w++) 
  {
    cout << B[w] << " ";
  }
cout << ")" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

the output will be B= (0 0 0 )

Comment: This is not the simplest way to output as desired, not for a given size of 2 or 3. And it does not give the desired output as stated.

Comment: please share your opinion.

Comment: Ima go out on a limb and say his opinion is that the answer should at least give the ops desired output.

Comment: Making the desired output (for 2 or 3 values, OP does not seem very decided on this) is a one-liner without any issues of unwanted spaces. OP however did not ask for the simplest version. Possibly because he wants to upscale to more values. In my opinoin this is too much guesswork for making an answer.

Comment: @George True, once it becomes clear what output OP actually wants. Now that OP accepted an answer, it seems kind of clear, conflicts however with what OP stated as desired output. But I also doubt the "simplest", which I would accept as description for the first option in the answer by Jonas Reich.

Comment: you can use if conditions for the desired output,  one that does not have extra blank space . and when the conditions meet the last index of the element it   "\b" it and output a brace without any extra space at the end

Comment: Yes you can and you'd end up with the currently accepted answer by Patryk. More elegant solutions (yes plural, two in fact) are however found in at least one other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one if you want:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int B[3]={0};
    cout << "B=(";
    for (int w = 0; w <2; w++) {
        cout << B[w];
        if(w != 1) cout << " ";
    }
    cout << ")" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
B=(0 0)
```

The line `if(w != 1)` checks whether you 've reached the last element of the array. In this case the last index is 1, but in general the if statement should be: `if(w != n-1)` where `n` is the size of the array.

Comment: Using `\b` is not portable.

Comment: Warning: backspace doesn't work quite as expected on all consoles. It's better to not print the final space at all.

Comment: I'm just trying to be as precise to the desired solution as I can.